# Transition from one page to another in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight-4.0

While using Silverlight, if you have a lot of pages, what are the techniques that can be used for transition from one page to another.

Basically, I want to create a MainPage that would have different sections, let's say TopLeft, TopRight, BottomRight, MainArea. These different sections will load different pages with a transition.

Edit> I think the question was not as clear at it could have been... I want to get an "effect" while another page loads in the same area. Something like "slide in", "slide out", etc.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [Fluid Layout](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/SilverlightTV/Creating-Rich-Interactions-Using-Blend-4-Transition-Effects-Fluid-Layout-and-Layout-States-Silverlig)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [deep linking](http://www.vsj.co.uk/articles/display.asp?id=790) mechanism in Silverlight which is based on the hash part of the URL (`#`) to perform navigation without reloading the hosting page.

Comment: Thanks for your response Darin. I am actually looking for "transition" effects between a page. Like, I don't want the other page to "appear", I want it to "slide in" or "slide out" or "some other effect".

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight business application template can be useful for your requirements. and see this sample aslo
http://gallery.expression.microsoft.com/en-us/SLNPWTSL4?SRC=Home